# How does tensorflow autograph work with tf.placeholder as function argument?

Tags: tensorflow

How to pass tf.placeholder as argument into a python function transformed by [autograph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph)?

```
from tensorflow.contrib import autograph

@autograph.convert()
def foo(s):
    sep = ' '
    res = s.split(sep)
    return sep.join(res)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
y = foo(x)
```

gives the following error when I attempt to export the graph with [`tf.saved_model.simple_save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/simple_save):

> tensorflow.contrib.autograph.pyct.transformer.AutographParseError:
>   AttributeError: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(), dtype=string) has no
>   attribute split Offending source: s.split

`print(autograph.to_code(foo))` shows the following. I wish I could write a python function that handles the argument `s` as a string instead of a Tensor.

```
def tf__foo(s):
  try:
    with tf.name_scope('foo'):
      sep = ' '
      res = ag__.converted_call(s.split, True, False, {}, sep)
      return ag__.converted_call(sep.join, True, False, {}, res)
  except:
    ag__.rewrite_graph_construction_error(ag_source_map__)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/var/folders/jc/0jvly0mn6sb5rk92tst0rgnr0000gn/T/tmp5pj2fv2o.py",
>   line 7, in tf__foo
>           res = ag__.converted_call(s.split, True, False, {}, sep)
>       AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'split'

Notes

- Exporting the graph for serving predictions. Hence there is no need to feed data to the placeholder.
- [Eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) not enabled
  as it is not compatible with
  [tf.placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder)
- On tensorflow 1.10, python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Autograph just does not convert *any* python code to tensorflow operations. It focuses (for now?) on control flow -- especially `while_loop`s,  which are really something.

So to split a string in autograph you still need to call good old `tf.string_split`.

Actually since your function does not contain any control flow operation, it does not really benefit from autograph features.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this info, indeed the current focus of autograph seems to be [control flow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/LIMITATIONS.md). I'm not sure whether I missed something, but your answer doesn't address why placeholder can't be an argument for an autograph'ed function.